# Android TextSwitcher couldn't wrap content width after set text

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using TextSwitcher to put fade in - fade out animation when I set text. But having some problems with wrapping the content by its width when the text is changed.

Following is my TextSwitched xml:

```
<TextSwitcher
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:background="#ffffff"
                            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="1dp" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                        </TextSwitcher>
```

I have list of strings and when ever I change from long word e.g. "Hello World" to "World", the textswitcher does not wrap the width for the string "World", rather it keeps the width of the word of "Hello World".

In nutshell, the width remains fixed for the maximum width of the longest word.

Please suggest!!!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By default, subclasses of  `ViewAnimator` will adjust size to their largest children.

To avoid this, try adding `android:measureAllChildren="false"` to your `TextSwitcher`

Comment: Add android:animateLayoutChanges="true" to animate the width/height of the button. It's imperfect (only shrinks the width after changing text, but expands the width before transitioning to larger text) but it mostly gets the job done. Try it, you'll see what I mean.