# Update parent of TextSwitcher when text changed

Tags: android, android-view

Im using a textSwither for hide/show a part of text like this way :

```
txtDescription.setInAnimation(in);
txtDescription.setOutAnimation(out);
txtDescription.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                TextView textView = new TextView(ShopContentDetailActivity.this);
                textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.NightDark));
                return textView;
            }
        });
```

And call this method for change text :

```
private void changeDescription() {
        if (displayShort)
            txtDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(shortDescription));
        else txtDescription.setText(fullDescription);
        displayShort = !displayShort;
    }
```

My problem is when user touch textSwitcher to display text and touch again to hide it ,the height of parent view (a linear layout ) of textSwitcher remain as when text is displayed and dont change its height.
How can i update the parent view when text change ? (its ok when touch for display full text)

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my problem in this way : (I think TextSwutcher change visibility of TextViews to **INVISIBLE** not **GONE** then i use this trck)

```
 private void changeDescription() {
        if (displayShort) {
            txtDescription.setCurrentText(null);  // this line change invisible textView visible but without text and make it height 0 and then set the second textView text
            txtDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(shortDescription));
        } else txtDescription.setText(shopContent.getDescription());
        displayShort = !displayShort;

    }
```

But there is a problem that is not so important for my case: when you hide a part of text its blink.
if i resolve it i will update my answer.

Comment: I were about to raport Issue do Google, but I came across your answer. 
Initial state of TextViews is indeeed GONE, after text change is INVISIBLE. Maybe it should be reported anyway

Comment: Any other solution to this? Setting the text as null is quite visible on the UI.

Comment: Came across a simple solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620310/android-textswitcher-couldnt-wrap-content-width-after-set-text